# Select DateTime field based only on the date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, date, datetime

How can I query a DateTime field only based on the date ignoring the time in the field?

```
select * from TABLE_NAME
where DATE = '2020-01-08'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by this way, [demo in db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=99fa8c2087dc26ac70e8f9729b6d9e72)

```
select * from TABLE_NAME
where CAST([DATE] AS DATE) = CAST('2020-01-08' AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do date comparison:

```
mydatetime >= cast('2020-01-08' as date) and mydatetime < cast('2020-01-09' as date)
```

Or you can `cast()` your datetime to a `date` (which is shorter to write, but far less efficient, since it cannot take advantage of an index on the datetime column):

```
cast(mydatetime as date) = cast('2020-01-08' as date)
```